# without datasource object how can perform server operation in kendo grid

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am using Kendo UI jQuery version, and I haven't `kendo.dll` in my ASP.NET MVC application.

I am using jQuery kendo grid, now with out `kendo.dll` I haven't DataSourceRequest object in C# so I can't perform server side filter and short operation with kendo grid.

Can any one suggest me how I can will overcome this issue?

```
public ActionResult test([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request)
{
}
```

How to make own `DataSourceRequest` in c# or need I write custom Attribute for this?

Comment: You need to write a custom attribute for it by parsing the incomming request. But why the do you not want to use the dll?

Comment: @ChristianGollhardt acctully we haven't Kendo Dll Licence, we have only kendo jquery licence so

Comment: It is cheaper to buy the license then paying developers that reinvent the wheel